# Why should I cast to cl_platform_info when using getInfo?

Tags: opencl

My book uses getInfo() like this

```
platforms[i].getInfo((cl_platform_info)CL_PLATFORM_NAME , &platformName);
```

But it works fine as

```
platforms[i].getInfo(CL_PLATFORM_NAME , &platformName);
```

...platforms is set like this:

```
cl::vector <cl::Platform> platforms;
cl::Platform::get(&platforms);
```

Comment: Maybe the author is too zealous... ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For my own plain C code projects, I avoid unneeded typecasts. Others occasionally claim unnecessary type casts help them understand their code. A complicating factor is that to a C programmer, C++ itself requires unnecessary type casts (when assigning a void pointer to a non-void pointer). Some programmers who do both C and C++ coding forget about this C/C++ difference and end up putting unnecessary type casts in C code. Another cause of unnecessary type casts is overly "helpful" compiler warning settings: http://notabs.org/coding/warningLevel4.htm. In my opinion, a type cast (at least in C code) is often a red flag that warns the reader the code is doing something unusual, non-standard, or quick and dirty. In your example, I would argue against a type cast even if all compilers required it. If all compilers required a type cast, then it should have been embedded in the definition of CL_PLATFORM_NAME. My guess is that the author of the book used some C++ compiler and warning level that forced him to use the type cast. I suggest avoiding unnecessary type casts.